# Parse: saveInBackgroundWithBlock is not working when the app is in background in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject

I'm making use of [Parse](https://parse.com/) in my iOS Application. I'm able to save the App data in Parse using PFObject. So far everything is working fine. But when the application is background mode, Parse is not saving the PFObject in server. I'm using '`saveInBackgroundWithBlock`' to save the data.

So, My question is, will '`saveInBackgroundWithBlock`' method work when the app is in background?

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you have enabled BackGround task for application.

Comment: Yes. @iOSWeblineindia.

Answer (score 0):

The main use of `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` is while the app is in the foreground. It allows you to perform the asynchronous save operation off the main thread. This is different from when the app is in the background.

When the app is in the background, perhaps your best bet is to use `saveEventually`, and Parse will eventually push it to the server.